# Is there a way to remove anchor tag from url?

Tags: react-admin

Default url for home page http://localhost/#/
Default url when navigating from side menu to a resource is http://localhost/#/

How do I remove this anchor tag from all my routes? (or even some)

Edit (update): This worked!
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Admin.md#history

Comment: I assume this is for `react-admin`, but the documentation you provided doesn't say anything about how to remove the hashtag, just that you can create your own history. Is that what you've done?

Comment: Thanks mate. You saved a lot of time.